# Updating a table after Inserting into another MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables i am trying to run a query on `Table1` `Table2`

I run a `SELECT` query on `Table1` to return all rows that match a specific date.

I then insert all the returned rows into `Table2`.

I then want to `UPDATE` `Table1` timestamp after the `INSERT`

The problem I am having is with the `UPDATE` part.

Here is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO Invoices(...)
UPDATE SiteInvoice SET  LastInvoiceDate = CURDATE()
SELECT ... FROM SiteInvoice 
    WHERE lastinvoicedate IS NOT Null AND LastInvoiceDate> CURDATE() - INTERVAL InvoiceFreq WEEK
```

Comment: You can't update and insert at the same time

Comment: Would adding an after insert trigger on the Invoices table to handle the update of SiteInvoices would do the job. Not sure if that would be the best way to go

Comment: It is a valid possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d), I can not update and insert at the same time. I have added a trigger to the invoice table to update after insert